# Wordpress theme memory leak

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, memory-leaks

I'm developing a custom wordpress theme for one of my clients and I encounter several `memory exhausted` errors.

At this moment I have set the available memory at 64mb and even I can set this higher but I don't want to do this; but optimize my work. Also the client insists to use two plugins (Visual Composer & Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer) that takes some more memory.

My question is:
How can I see what queries, objects, variables use the memory and how I can free those.

I tried a bunch of plugins (Debug Bar, Memory Viewer, p3, Query Monitor) but they only tell me how much memory I use and nothing specific.

Can you point me to some articles about this subject (I searched for two days but nothing clear was returned about this subject).

Most of the memory errors appear after I make ajax calls. Is there something I can do to prevent memory overload in the PHP function?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the code where the memory leak happens - However the problem is somewhere around wp_head execution. My investigations reveal a jump in memory use at that time. The question is about general guidelines and things to do in case you need to debug these kind of issues.
    // $args is printed

```
Array
(
[post_type] => estate_property
[post_status] => publish
[paged] => 1
[posts_per_page] => 30
[meta_key] => prop_featured
[orderby] => meta_value
[order] => DESC
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => property_price
                [value] => 0
                [type] => numeric
                [compare] => >=
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => property_price
                [value] => 50000000
                [type] => numeric
                [compare] => <=
            )

    )

[cache_results] => 
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

)


$prop_selection =   new WP_Query($args);
```

.....

Comment: Are you uploading and processing images? Note that 64Mb is not much for an uncompressed image in memory.

Comment: I only get post attachments (images) and display them, not uploading. Is something i can do on this side ?

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I posted the code however the question is about steps and things to do when investigating these kind of issues. I noticed that a lot of memory is used until that wp_query so probably i need to investigate other parts of the code.

Comment: I solved the issues by setting, update_post_meta_cache and update_post_term_cache to false . However the question remain - how i can see what is eating the memory and how i can free it.